# Why my 2 same titan x have different memory size?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

Why my 2 same titan x have different memory size? They differ by 1mb. Is it normal? Also, why the memory usage is different when running on caffe, which supposedly assign same number of images to the 2 gpus?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first GPU (GPU 0) is running some extra processes. When multiple NVIDIA GPUs are connected via SLI, only one of the GPUs performs the PhysX while the rest of the processes are distributed. So there is a slight extra load on one of the GPUs. A small portion of your primary device will always be reserved for some default processes.